# StackOverflow When Trying to Create a New ViewModel in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I've been trying for the past few days to create a new viewmodel and display it on the main shellview of my application. Currently, I've been able to get the page to load using `ActivateItemAsync` However that takes over the entire page. I currently want it to sit above the activeitem. Here is the view for the page:

```
  <!-- Notification Bar -->
  <UserControl 
            x:Name="NotificationMessage"
            Visibility="{Binding IsNotificationMessageVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=collapsed}"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"

            />


        <!-- Main Frame -->
        <Frame 
               x:Name="ActiveItem"  
               NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" 
               Padding="10"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
               />
```

As you can see from above I have two rows with one being a notification bar that will appear if the user has a notification. I currently want this to be hidden only if a notification is available. However, I am unable to make the notification show up within the page. When I try I receive a stack overflow notification due to it looping. Below is the ViewModel code for the above view:

private _notificationtMessage;

```
    public NotificationViewModel NotificationMessage
    {
        get {
            _notificationtMessage= new NotificationViewModel ();
            return _notificationtMessage; 
        }
        set { 
            _notificationtMessage= value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => NotificationMessage);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsNotificationVisible);
        }
    }



    public bool IsNotificationVisible
    {
        get
        {
            bool b = false;
            if(Database.GetNotification().Title.Length !=0)
            {
                b = true;
                this.NotificationMessage = new NotificationViewModel ();
            }
            return b;
        }
    }
```

My main question is how do I create a new instance of this Model within my ShellViewModel and display it in my ShellView?

Comment: This class instantiates itself when the IsNotificationVisible property getter is called, probably where your stack overflow happens

Comment: The reason of SO exception is this line `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsNotificationVisible);`, you notify `IsNotificationVisible` property change and it updates `NotificationMessage`, which updates `IsNotificationVisible` again and it goes to infinite loop. What is the reason of notifying `IsNotificationVisible` change in `NotificationMessage`? Usually you will need to notify the property, when visibility was changed, not the vise versa

Comment: @Charleh @PavelAnikhouski  Thanks, Removing the `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsNotificationVisible);` stopped the recursive loop! Thank you so much. I no longer am receiving the stackOverflow error. However, the NotificationMessage is still not showing even though `Database.GetNotification().Title.Length !=0` is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create an object in a getter. Try this and make sure that you have defined a view for `NotificationViewModel` according to the conventions:

```
private NotificationViewModel _notificationtMessage = new NotificationViewModel();
public NotificationViewModel NotificationMessage
{
    get
    {
        return _notificationtMessage;
    }
    set
    {
        _notificationtMessage = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => NotificationMessage);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsNotificationVisible);
    }
}


public bool IsNotificationVisible
{
    get
    {
        return Database.GetNotification().Title.Length != 0;
    }
}
```